# not able to refresh the ListView on Spinner's selected item to get new data from url

Tags: android, json, listview, refresh, spinner

1. I am not able to refresh the list view on spinner item select.
2. I want to build new url based on items value of spinner to fetch new json data and converting into listview.
3. you can also help me telling a way how can i create a method to just pass the new url to get new data.
4. Main problem is same as title 
   Your every help will be appreciated.

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

   ```
   String [] array_values = {"All "," 5"," 4"," 3"," 2"," 1"};
   final Spinner spinner = view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

   final ArrayAdapter<String> spinner_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_values);
   spinner_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
   spinner.setAdapter(spinner_adapter);

   final String spinnerValue = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
   url = "http://website.com/demo.php?pswd=kvpswd";

   listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.demo_list_view);
   adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this.getActivity(), List);
   listView.setAdapter(adapter);

   spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
         //  listView.setAdapter(null);
         String spinnerValue = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
           url = "http://website.com/demo.php?pswd="+spinnerValue;
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
       public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

       }
   });

   // Creating volley request obj
   JsonArrayRequest Requset = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
           new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
               @Override
               public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                   Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                   hidePDialog();

                   // Parsing json
                   for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                       try {

                           JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                           DataFetcher datafetcher = new DataFetcher();

                           datafetcher.set1(obj.getString("item1"));
                           datafetcher.set2(obj.getString("item2"));
                           datafetcher.set3(obj.getString("item3"));
                           datafetcher.set4(obj.getString("item4"));
                           datafetcher.set5(obj.getString("item5"));
                           datafetcher.set6(obj.getString("item6"));
                           datafetcher.set7(obj.getString("item7"));
                           datafetcher.set8(obj.getString("item8"));

                           // adding list to list array
                           List.add(datafetcher);

                       } catch (JSONException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }

                   }

                   // notifying list adapter about data changes
                   // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
               }
           }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
       @Override
       public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
           VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
           hidePDialog();

       }
   });
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make method for api call and pass url and set data into list view.
below method pass into spinner selection time.

```
 private void callApiData(String url){
    // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest Requset = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                            DataFetcher datafetcher = new DataFetcher();

                            datafetcher.set1(obj.getString("item1"));
                            datafetcher.set2(obj.getString("item2"));
                            datafetcher.set3(obj.getString("item3"));
                            datafetcher.set4(obj.getString("item4"));
                            datafetcher.set5(obj.getString("item5"));
                            datafetcher.set6(obj.getString("item6"));
                            datafetcher.set7(obj.getString("item7"));
                            datafetcher.set8(obj.getString("item8"));

                            // adding list to list array
                            List.add(datafetcher);
                            setAdapter();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hidePDialog();

        }
    });
}
```

and also make one separate method for adapter setting.

```
  private void setAdapter(){
    if(adpter==null){
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this.getActivity(), List);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    else{
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not working properly..it add new data from url to the end of listview without clearing the old data..please help me

Comment: when you getting data that time list will be cleared like used List.clear() method before getting data. // List in your array list object.